# Replace symbols with values in expression and print expression out

Tags: c++, c

*For example,* I have an expression like this passed into `macro CHECK()`:

```
CHECK((var1 + var2) * 4 <= var3))
```

in which: `var1, var2, var3` is any variables (pointers, variable, array, number, class...)

I want to replace `var1, var2, var3` with their values and print them out like this:

```
(15 + 16) * 4 <= 20
```

Is it possible with `C`/`C++`? I've not had idea yet.
Printing `(var1 + var2) * 4 <= var3)` from `macro CHECK()` is very easy, just use `#` operator.
But replacing symbols with value and printing out as an expression seems uneasy.

Comment: What's the actual definition of `CHECK()`?? Macro expansion is done as a simple textual replacement **before** any c/c++ code is compiled, and certainly doesn't apply at runtime! Go for templates, if you want to have something useful in c++.

Comment: Upvoter explain please? How is this a valid question?

Comment: C != C++, and in C++ macros are rarely the way to go.

Comment: >>What's the actual definition of CHECK()?? ---> That's actually Im asking for

Answer (score 0):

If you need to evaluate and print arguments of a predefined macro I doubt there is an easy solution. If you just need to create and print an expression with evaluated arguments it can be done with `#` operator like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT_CHECK(var1, type1, var2, type2, var3, type3) \
printf("(%"#type1" + %"#type2") * 4 <= %"#type3"\n", var1, var2, var3)

void main(void) {
    PRINT_CHECK(0, d, 1 + 2, d, 3 * 4, d);
}
```

As a result

```
$ gcc example.c -o example && ./example 
(0 + 3) * 4 <= 12
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to have a general expression passed into that macro. Maybe we need an expression parser?

Comment: If you find something ready it can be solution. However in general just in time evaluator is not a simple thing.